# Warning in C: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast

Tags: c, casting

I keep getting this error when compiling my program. This is just a small part of my code, so if needed I will provide the rest of the code. Any ideas on why this is occuring?

```
void strip_quotes(char s[]) {
   if (s[0]=='"') s=s+1;
   if (s[strlen(s)-2]=='"') s[strlen(s)-2]=NULL;
}
```

Comment: why did you write `(int)s;` ???

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the statement `(int)s;`?

Comment: You may want to change `s[strlen(s)-2]=NULL;` to `s[strlen(s)-2]='\0'`;

Comment: what are you trying to do?
you were casting s to an integer and then trying to set it to null?!

Comment: which line has the warning on it according to the compiler?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Ah sry, I edited it out.

Comment: Most probably it is due to assigning `NULL` to `s[strlen(s)-2]` (with `NULL` defined as `(void *)0` by your compiler). Also consider escaping double-quotes with a backslash in your if-statements (e.g. `if (s[0] == '\"';`. Furthermore, consider checking before-hand that `strlen(s)` is greater than 1, so `s[strlen(s)-2]` always refers to the intended memory. Also, `(int)s` is totally wrong. Finally, consider using a loop, so the signature of the function is in par with its code.

Comment: Ace, also, when you're debugging stuff, having both parts of an if statement on the same line makes it harder to figure out what the compiler is telling you.  General rule is never put both parts on the same line, but especially not while you're debugging.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [Dave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1180785/dave) has already correctly pointed out the reason for the compiler error:

```
 s[strlen(s)-2]=NULL; /* = (void*)0 */
```

There is another bug in the code that won't cause a compiler error:

```
if (s[0]=='"') s=s+1;
```

the increment of `s` will not be visible to the caller, as C passes by value including pointers (see http://c-faq.com/ptrs/passptrinit.html). Options for correcting:

- shift the content of the array to the left using [`memmove()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memmove) (or some other copy mechanism)
- pass the address of the pointer (a `char**`)
- return a pointer to `s`

Changing the content of `s` is preferable as it avoids a possible problem if the array was dynamically allocated: only pointers returned by `malloc()` (or `calloc()` and `realloc()`) can be passed to `free()`. If the value of `s` is changed then it cannot be `free()`d via `s`.

Note that:

```
void strip_quotes(char s[]) {
```

is equivalent:

```
void strip_quotes(char* s) {
```

incase you were confused as to were pointers are used in the code.

Answer (score 6):

You are setting a character of `s` to `NULL`. The proper way to add a null character to a string is to use `'\0'`.

To explain the message, `NULL` is likely defined as `(void*)0`, so when you assign it, you are converting `void*` to `char`, hence the warning.

Answer (score 0):

Dave got it, but I'll try to add a bit.

NULL is a pointer of type void*, which can be assigned to any pointer type.  If you are setting a pointer to a value that can never be used to represent valid memory, use NULL.

'\0', aka NUL, is ascii value 0 and is used to terminate strings.  It is of type char.  http://www.december.com/html/spec/ascii.html .

Answer (score 0):

```
void strip_quotes(char s[]) {
    int len = strlen(s);
    if(s[len-1] == '"')
        s[--len] = '\0';
    if(s[0]=='"')
        memmove(s, s+1, len);
}
```